# "Theorems 1 and 2 imply" vs. "Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 imply"

Tags: article-writing

To convey that
$$\text{Theorem 1} \wedge \text{Theorem 2} \implies A$$
which style is better?

> Theorems 1 and 2 imply $A$.

> Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 imply $A$.

Which style manuals prefer which form?

(This question concerns the repetition of the word *theorem*, not the capitalization.)

Comment: There are style manuals? Where?

Comment: [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch12/ch12_toc.html) has a math chapter, [AMS style guide](https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/index.html)... no style guide can cover every situation, but if there is a style guide that speaks to this issue, I would like to know, and it is helpful to have such questions on SE because the style guides themselves are often paywalled.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the information

Comment: The first one looks better to me.

Comment: Looks better to me too, but when I am asked to offer stylistic comments on someone's paper, I try to justify them with reference to a style manual, hence the question.

Comment: I can't speak to what style manuals, but *I* prefer "Theorems 1 and 2". Consider the extrapolation where more theorems are involved. Would you *really* want to write "Theorem 1, Theorem 2, Theorem 3, ..., and Theorem $n$ imply ..." vs "Theorems 1, 2, 3, ..., $n$ imply ..."? ... In any case, if the Chicago Manual has guidance regarding "Presidents Smith and Jones" vs "President Smith and President Jones", then perhaps that would apply here. The [Writing StackExchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com) may have insights.

Comment: I agree with your preference. For the purposes of this question, I'm looking for something more than a well-reasoned opinion--ideally a reference to a style manual, or failing that, quotations from well-copyedited, published references.

Comment: I would look for articles by a native speaker... e.g. a British or American author born in UK or USA, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Besides style, I think there's an issue of ambiguous interpretation:
  "Theorems 1 and 2 imply..." suggests to me that $\mbox{Thm}1\ \&\ \mbox{Thm}2\Rightarrow\mbox{Thm}3$.
But "Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 imply..." might more easily be interpreted to mean
  $\mbox{Thm}1\Rightarrow\mbox{Thm}3\ \ \&\ \ \mbox{Thm}2\Rightarrow\mbox{Thm}3$

Comment: The same ambiguity is present in either construction. A less ambiguous way to convey the latter meaning is "Theorem 1 or 2 implies ... " or "Theorems 1 and 2 alike imply ..."

Comment: @Max Sure -- I was trying to suggest that you might want to partition your question into two sub-questions: which style is best when you mean one thing, versus which style is best when you mean the other.

Answer (score 1):

> Theorems $1$ and $2$ imply $A.$
>
> Theorem $1$ and Theorem $2$ imply $A.$

The first phrasing is a tad more idiomatic than the second one, but nonetheless, they are in practice equivalent: each can be construed as either statement $(\text A1)$ or statement $(\text A2)$ below (admittedly, the $(\text A1)$ reading is a little more immediate)!

**Suggestions:**

- > $(\text{Theorem 1} \wedge \text{Theorem 2}) \implies A\tag{A1}$

  Theorems $1$ and $2$ ***collectively/together/jointly/conjunctively implies*** $A.$
- $(\text{Theorem 1} \implies A) \land (\text{Theorem 2} \implies A) \tag{A2}$

  Theorems $1$ and $2$ ***each implies*** $A.$

Notice that adding the word ‘both’ to the two phrasings at the top doesn't aid disambiguation.

---

> Theorem $1$ or $2$ implies $A.$
>
> Theorem $1$ or Theorem $2$ implies $A.$

You didn't ask, but these ‘or’ phrasings have the same issue as above.

**Suggestions:**

- $(\text{Theorem 1} \lor \text{Theorem 2}) \implies A\tag{O1}$

  If Theorem $1$ or $2$ is true, then $A$ is true.

  Theorems $1$ and $2$ each implies $A.\quad$ (I.e., statement $(\text A2)$.)
- $(\text{Theorem 1} \implies A) \lor (\text{Theorem 2} \implies A) \tag{O2}$

  Theorem $1$ implies $A$ or Theorem $2$ implies $A.$

  Theorems $1$ and $2$ jointly implies $A.\quad$ (I.e., statement $(\text A1)$; [proof](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(1%7E12%7E5A)%7E4(1%7E5A)%7E2(2%7E5A)))